# Copy source code between two source locations in Clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I am writing a Clang plugin that should extract some information out of my source file. I've obtained two source locations with the help of `ASTContext` and its `getFullLoc` function.

How can I extract/copy the source code between these two source locations?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "extract/copy the source code between these two location"? Are you trying to parse the AST? Edit source code? Something else?